# "Cannot resolve symbol" for all classes from external library in Intellij

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, dependencies

I have an Intellij project that uses Gradle. I've added an external dependency in the form of a `JAR` file in the `libs` folder, and added it to `build.gradle` using this:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: '*.jar')
```

Intellij recognizes it as a dependency, since it allows me to browse the file and view its contents, plus it suggests the packages I can import.

[image]
[image]

However, I can't use any of the classes contained. Intellij says `Cannot resolve symbol '[classname]'`. This occurs in both the library itself and my project files.

[image]
[image]

Other Gradle dependencies work fine, like those in the form `compile "some.group:artifact:version"`.

I've tried all of the fixes I've found online for this, including:

- Invalidating Cache/Restarting
- Deleting the `.idea` file

How can I use this local `JAR` file as a dependency?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the jar you've attached contains `*.java` files instead of the compiled `*.class` files.

Library dependencies will work only for the jars with the `.class` files. Find a library jar instead of the source jar for this dependency and place it to the `libs` directory, reimport the project.

Comment: So `.java` files work for Gradle dependencies, but not those in the `libs` folder? Because I have other dependencies that have `.java` files.

Comment: Yes, for the `.java` dependencies to work they need to be in a module source root so that IDE runs Java compiler on these files. Your other modules [can depend on this module](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/working-with-module-dependencies.html#add-a-new-dependency). For the jar dependencies Java requires the `.class` files as it will not automatically compile `.java` files inside the jars. This won't work neither in the command line nor in any IDE.

Comment: Could you explain how to add the jar as a "module source root"? I've tried a couple of different things related to that but I'm not familiar enough with the Intellij to do that.

Comment: You need to unpack the jar into the module source root, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-content-roots.html.

Comment: Alright, I extracted the jar as an archive into a folder, then followed the "Add a new content root" section. But since I'm using Gradle, it says "`Module [main module] is imported from Gradle. Any changes made in its configuration may be lost after reimporting.`" And when I refresh Gradle, the new module source root disappears. Is there a way to avoid this?

Comment: Setup Gradle multi-project  so that your code lives in one project and this dependency in another, configure dependencies between these projects: https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2017/03/webinar-recording-composite-builds-with-gradle/.